# How to separate json with lists as values into separate json objects with python?

Tags: python, json

So, I am trying to achieve the following. I have a json with following structure:

```
json = {'key1':[value11,value12], 'key2':[value12, value22]}
```

I want to separate each value in particular key to from a separate json while retaining its key as follows:

```
json1 = {'key1':value11,'key2':value12}
json2 = {'key1':value12,'key2':value22}
```

Builtin json module does not seems to help

Comment: Do all the lists have the same length? What happens, if they don't have?

Comment: They always always have same length. Incase they don't, then logically the later jsons values should be None

Comment: Perhaps you want a `list` of those `dict` objects instead of separate variables?

Comment: Even that would be good enough

Comment: `[{key:json[key]} for key in json.keys()]` shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: @Abhyudai no, because he does not want to have a list of the items of one key, rather the n-th item of every key...

Comment: @MartinSteinborn exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hacky and I could not figure out to use the inline for loops, but it works for me:
I first created the empty array, and due to the for loops you should be able to catch the case if sth should be none...

```py
json = {'key1':[11, 12], 'key2':[21, 22]}
max_len = max([len(json[key]) for key in json.keys()])
data = [{}] * max_len
# data = [{} for _ in range(max_len)]
for i in range(max_len):
    for key in json.keys():
        data[i][key] = json[key][i] if json[key][i] else None
print(data)
```

gives:

```
[{'key1': 11, 'key2': 21}, {'key1': 12, 'key2': 22}]
```